# Return only 1 address for each customer

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to query the addresses of top 500 customers (best buyers). Many companies have multiple addresses.

The tables with data:

- CustomerInfo
- CustomerAddress
- TransactionInfo
- TransactionElements

My query looks this way:

```
select Customername, CustomerStreet --etc 
from CustomerInfo 
join CustomerAddress on CustomerID = Add_CustID
join  TransactionInfo on Trn_CustID = CustomerID
JOIN TransactionElements ON Trn_CustID = TrE_CustID


GROUP BY CustomerName, CustomerStreet --etc
ORDER BY SUM (TrE_TranValue) DESC
```

It returns multiple addresses of a single company, I need just one.

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to use a CTE (Common Table Expression) if you're on SQL Server 2005 and newer (you aren't specific enough in that regard).

With this CTE, you can partition your data by some criteria - i.e. your `CustomerId` - and have SQL Server number all your rows starting at 1 for each of those "partitions", ordered by some criteria.

So try something like this:

```
;WITH CustomerAndAddress AS
(
   SELECT 
       c.Customername, ca.CustomerStreet ,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY c.CustomerId ORDER BY ca.AddressID DESC) AS 'RowNum'
   FROM 
       dbo.CustomerInfo c
   INNER JOIN 
       dbo.CustomerAddress ca ON c.CustomerID = ca.Add_CustID       
   WHERE
      ......
)
SELECT 
   Customername, CustomerStreet 
FROM 
   CustomerAndAddress
WHERE
   RowNum = 1
```

Here, I am selecting only the "first" entry for each "partition" (i.e. for each `CustomerId`) - ordered by some criteria (I just arbitrarily picked `AddressID` from the address - adapt as needed) you need to define in your CTE.

Does that approach what you're looking for??

Comment: I have examined the database and I need to choose the current address. I dont know which column identifies this one. Most likely its the int value (it has to be the highest among the other addresses). I only need to choose the one where this column value is the highest.

Comment: @user1646678: well, then, once you know which column identifies the most recent address - just place that column into the `ORDER BY` inside the `OVER (....)` clause and you're done

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will work from sqlserver 2005+. I also suggest adding some aliasses to your tables and refer to those.

```
select CI.Customername, CA.CustomerStreet --etc 
from CustomerInfo CI
cross apply 
(select top 1 Customername, CustomerStreet --etc
from CustomerAddress where CustomerID = CI.Add_CustID) CA
join  TransactionInfo TI on TI.Trn_CustID = CI.CustomerID
JOIN TransactionElements ON CI.CustomerID = TE.TrE_CustID
GROUP BY CustomerName, CustomerStreet --etc
ORDER BY SUM (TrE_TranValue) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

If `CustomerInfo` has many `CustomerAddress`, this query will make `CustomerInfo` returned for each `CustomerAddress` (a cartesian product) :

`join CustomerAddress on CustomerID = Add_CustID`

So if you need to get only one address you have to add conditions needed to choose single `CustomerAddress` :

`join CustomerAddress on CustomerID = Add_CustID where <conditions>`